# AS3 - How to make sure two shapes are congruent

Tags: actionscript-3, image-processing

I have two shapes where I drag and drop one shape to the another shape.

I need code for collision to check if two shapes are congruent or not.

Comment: So, what's the problem? You don't know how to drag objects? You don't know how to drop objects? You don't know how to check collisions? Please show us what you have so far in terms of code and elaborate where do you stuck and why.

Comment: @mrmath **Not enough info** to answer your **programming** question. In AS3 you either have an object of type **Bitmap** (pixel data) or **Graphics** (vector/shape data). In AS3 doing collision detection will tell you True or False if touching (regardless of shape outline). Either you're wrong about collision detection for shapes or you're not telling us everything. **(1)** Show these shapes for assessment. **(2)** Are the shapes of type `bitmapData` or `Graphics`? **(3)** Did you first check how others do it on the web? We can only help with your existing code or explain code-related concept.